# Typescript: Is there a way to extend an interface, but modify property names?

Tags: typescript

Have a look at this simple interface:

```
inteface Foo {
  bar: any
}
```

I want to create this interface from the above one:

```
inteface Foo2 {
  bar$: any
}
```

in other words, I want to append `$` to every property of `Foo` Interface.

Of course something like this didn't work:

```
type Foo2 = {
    [(K in keyof Foo) + '$']: Observable<Foo[K]>
}
```

Comment: Nope, no way to mutate property names in an arbitrary way like that. (Unless you are willing to have a name map, ie `type nameMap = { bar: 'bar$' }` with all names).

Comment: That's sad :-( Thanks though!

Comment: You want [this feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) which does not (currently) exist.  Maybe go there and comment or give a ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, @jcalz, I've thumbed up